# Serialising with cattrs and want to omit field x1 string field

Tags: python, serialization, python-attrs

Using [cattrs](https://cattrs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to structure data and I want to omit x1 string field.

I want to perform a trivial cleanup on strings that have been passed in except for the password field.

I can get it to work on *all* strings

```
from attrs import define
from cattrs import Converter

MYDATA = {
           "hostname": "MYhostNAme ", 
           "port": 389, 
           "adminuser": " cn=admin, dc=acme, dc=com", 
           "adminpass": " ADmin "
          }

@define
class _LDAP:
  hostname: str                                                                                                          
  port: int                                                                                                              
  adminuser: str                                                                                                         
  adminpass: str                                                                                                         
                  
def tidystr(text):
  return text.lower().translate(str.maketrans("", "", " \n\t\r"))                                                        
                                                                                                                         
class _Vars:
  converter = Converter()                                                                                                
  converter.register_structure_hook(str, lambda x, cls: tidystr(x))                                                      
  ldap = converter.structure(MYDATA, _LDAP)         
  
app = _Vars()
assert app.ldap.hostname == "myhostname"  # True
assert app.ldap.adminpass == "admin"      # True !!Not what I want!!
```

I can fool cattrs by passing in the adminpass field as Any

```
@define
class _LDAP:
  adminpass: Any
```

but this is a bit clunky.

[The docs](https://cattrs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html?highlight=omit) show how to omit individual fields - but I can't figure out how then I would call the tidystr function. Following the docs closely I would do

```
class Vars:                                                                                                                
  converter = Converter()                                                                                                
  hook = make_dict_structure_fn(_LDAP, converter, adminpass=override(omit=True))                                         
  converter.register_structure_hook(_LDAP, hook)                                                                       
  ldap = converter.structure(MYDATA, _LDAP)
```

which obviously won't work because tidystr() isn't being called.

I've tried various ways and am lost. The docs also [show](https://cattrs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-factory-hooks) something like what I'm trying to do but the example is changing the *keys* not the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of cattrs. Let's see how we can solve this.

First we need a way to recognize which fields you want to tidy up and which you don't. Looks like you'd like to apply tidying to all strings by default and opt-out for some fields.

## Option #1: [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype)

Use a NewType for the password field.

```py
from typing import NewType

from attrs import define

from cattrs import Converter

NonTidyStr = NewType("NonTidyStr", str)

MYDATA = {
    "hostname": "MYhostNAme ",
    "port": 389,
    "adminuser": " cn=admin, dc=acme, dc=com",
    "adminpass": " ADmin ",
}


@define
class _LDAP:
    hostname: str
    port: int
    adminuser: str
    adminpass: NonTidyStr


def tidystr(text):
    return text.lower().translate(str.maketrans("", "", " \n\t\r"))


class _Vars:
    converter = Converter()
    converter.register_structure_hook(str, lambda x, cls: tidystr(x))
    converter.register_structure_hook(NonTidyStr, lambda x, _: str(x))
    ldap = converter.structure(MYDATA, _LDAP)


app = _Vars()
assert app.ldap.hostname == "myhostname"  # True
assert app.ldap.adminpass == " ADmin "
```

(Any function taking a string will happily take a NewType based on it instead, and it'll actually be a string at runtime.)

## Option 2: [`Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated)

We can use `typing.Annotated` to build our own little mini system for structuring.

The class becomes:

```py
@define
class _LDAP:
    hostname: str
    port: int
    adminuser: str
    adminpass: Annotated[str, "notidy"]
```

Then, we need to create the appropriate hook:

```
from cattrs._compat import is_annotated

def is_no_tidy(t: Any) -> bool:
    return is_annotated(t) and "notidy" in t.__metadata__

converter.register_structure_hook_func(is_no_tidy, lambda x, _: str(x))
```

The implementation is a little gnarly since Python doesn't have super good type inspection capabilities, but we can use an internal cattrs function instead.

This approach is, in general, very powerful.

Option 3: wait for 22.3.0

I'm adding an option to override the structure and unstructure functions for individual fields in the next version. Then, you'll be able to do something like:

```py
hook = make_dict_structure_fn(_LDAP, converter, adminpass=override(structure_fn=str))                                         
converter.register_structure_hook(_LDAP, hook)
```

Can't promise a release date though ;)

Comment: thanks a lot ! I met a similar use case where I want to specify that a given field should be structured with a custom logic; I'll use your #1 suggestion. 
I would have LOVED the 3rd option - looking forward to 22.3.0